# Reversing Transition with Delays Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

Consider the following transition:

```js
function toggle() {
  var element = document.querySelector('.sr-block-left');
  element.classList.toggle("sr-visible");
}
```

```css
[class^=sr-block-],
[class*=" sr-block-"] {
  position: relative;
  --block-color: #ccc;
  --animation-speed: 200ms;
}

[class^=sr-block-] > .sr-block,
[class*=" sr-block-"] > .sr-block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: transform var(--animation-speed) cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
}

[class^=sr-block-].sr-block-left.sr-visible > .sr-block,
[class*=" sr-block-"].sr-block-left.sr-visible > .sr-block {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

[class^=sr-block-] > .sr-block:before,
[class*=" sr-block-"] > .sr-block:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--block-color);
  will-change: transform;
  transition: transform var(--animation-speed) calc(var(--animation-speed) + 200ms) cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
}

[class^=sr-block-].sr-block-left.sr-visible > .sr-block:before,
[class*=" sr-block-"].sr-block-left.sr-visible > .sr-block:before {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: right;
}

[class^=sr-block-].sr-block-left > .sr-block,
[class*=" sr-block-"].sr-block-left > .sr-block {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
}

[class^=sr-block-] > .sr-block-content,
[class*=" sr-block-"] > .sr-block-content {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0s calc(var(--animation-speed) + 200ms);
}

[class^=sr-block-].sr-visible > .sr-block-content,
[class*=" sr-block-"].sr-visible > .sr-block-content {
  opacity: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000;
}

/* Fix for SO */
.sr-block-left {
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="sr-block-left sr-visible">
  <div class="sr-block"></div>
  <div class="sr-block-content">
    <h1>Some awesome title</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle Visibility</button>
```

The purpose of this transition is to reveal content when it arrives in the viewport (as the user scrolls). It does this by simply adding the `sr-visible` class.

The issue I am having is that I would like the transition to reverse when the element leaves the viewport. The reason the transition needs to reverse despite not being 'in the viewport' is because there are cases where it will be in the viewport  but will not have the `sr-visible` class, this is due to a scrolling threshold that I have on certain elements.

In short, is it possible to reverse this transition in a similar way to the way it appears? It does not have to be exact the same transition, but the closer the better. The key is that the 'reveal' transition does no change.

I have tried playing around with `transition-delay` and various other things but have no had any luck thus far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different idea that rely on only translate where it can be easy to reverse. It also rely on one element that you make big enough and you simply slide it from left to right to create the needed effect.

For the demo purpose I simplified your code to only show the animation. As you can see I made the element 3 times bigger that the container that I translate by `2/3` of its width from left and right to hide.

```js
function toggle() {
  var element = document.querySelector('.sr-block');
  element.classList.toggle("sr-visible");
}
```

```css
.sr-block {
  position: relative;
  --block-color: #ccc;
  --animation-speed: 200ms;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}

.sr-block > .sr-block-content:before {
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   z-index:1;
   top:0;
   left:-100%;
   right:-100%;
   bottom:0;
   background:var(--block-color);
   transform:translateX(calc(-2*100%/3 - 2px));
   transition:
    transform calc(2*var(--animation-speed)) cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
}


.sr-block.sr-visible > .sr-block-content:before {
   transform:translateX(calc(2*100%/3  + 2px));
}

.sr-block > .sr-block-content h1 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0s calc(var(--animation-speed));
}

.sr-block.sr-visible > .sr-block-content h1{
  opacity: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="sr-block sr-visible">
  <div class="sr-block-content">
    <h1>Some awesome title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle Visibility</button>
```

I am using `-/+2px` to avoid some bad behabior due to rounding.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, however, there were specific reasons I was using `div.sr-block` as a separate element to `div.sr-block-content`, the main reason being that I need to be able to control the opacity of `.sr-block-content`, and not the children as these may have their own opacity values. The original HTML must remain the same if that is possible?

Comment: I also cannot put `overflow:hidden` on the parent element as it cannot disrupt styles of elements within in, for example, box-shadow.

Comment: That said, I believe this could work. I tried a similar method before and for some reason the animation was really glitchy, so I resorted to `scale`. I will try using translate on my HTML.

Comment: @BenCarey as I said, I simplified the code for the demo, you can easily adjust it by keeping the same structure if you understand the translate animation but it's not useful for the question to keep a lot of code, it's will be hard to understand

Comment: This is really frustrating... Your transition is better and does exactly what I need it to do, BUT, for some reason, on page load, my original transition that uses `scale` works significantly better. The elements that are already in the vieport on page load get revealed as soon as the DOM loads, and my original solutions works smoothly, whereas the translate one seems to start halfway through. This was why I ended up using `scale`...

Comment: @BenCarey can you share your full code (maybe a link) where I can see this behavior?

Comment: Is it possible to continue via email/whatsapp/chat instead as I can show you the link but obviously need to keep things confidential...

Comment: @BenCarey yes, go to my personnal website through my profile and we can chat there, you will find a chat widget there